# Xamarin Forms & Admob - Failed to load ad: 3 only on Android

Tags: xamarin.forms, admob

I have been receiving **Failed to load ad: 3** error from Admob through Xamarin Forms on Android for quite some time now. I have tried everything to resolve:

- Changing the version of Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Ads nuget package
- Checking my Android Manifest file
- Checking that I have the relevant permissions set
- Checked in with Admob, they say they can load my adUnits from their end
- Looking at my implementation, which seems okay since I can load test adds through the AddTestDevice method
- Cleared my Google Play Services stored data on my Android test device
- Reset my advertising Id

All I keep getting is the following message no matter what I do:

```
No fill from ad server.
Failed to load ad: 3
```

This happens for both Banner and Interstitial Ads, they used to work on the same Android test device but have now stopped working. iOS works perfectly.

Please help !

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/IXu_n-5ft4Q Refer to the similar issue.

Comment: Hi Lucas, Thanks for sharing. The solution that the link provides is to mediate to 3rd party ad networks, but I'd really like to know why admob isn't working on Xamarin Forms especially when it worked before.

Comment: Have you tried on another device ? Is it in production or alpha/beta ?

Comment: The version in production is working fine on Android, but the development version is the issue. Its not working on Android. I will try on another device and let you know how it goes.

Comment: I tried another physical device, and I am still getting the same error. Failed to load ad: 3

Comment: Does anyone know what version of Xamarin.Firebase.Ads I should be using to get ads working?